# Powershell command to prepend text before each file

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, azure-powershell

I am trying to build a PowerShell command to extract all files from multiple folder and combine into a single file.

Script:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $(Pipeline.Workspace)/Common_All/Drop_$(DropFolder)_Migrations -Filter "Release*" 
-Directory | Get-ChildItem -File -Filter *.sql | ForEach-Object { $_ |Get-Content;
 "GO" } | out-file $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/combined-script.sql
```

This returns combined script with "GO" appended after each file content

How do I prepend a text before each file content?

Answer (score 2):

```
ForEach-Object { "prepended text`n" + ($_ | Get-Content -raw) + "`nGO" }
```

It may also be done same way as you've appended GO.

```
ForEach-Object {"prepended text"; $_ |Get-Content; "GO" }
```

Comment: It does not prepend to the data, it actually appends